# Convey to user that they can input absolute numbers or percentages

Tags: forms, gui-design, input-fields

I have a quoting form in which I want users to have the ability to add a discount. The discounts can be added as percentage or absolute values. My current design is a text field and a dropdown for selecting absolute or percentage values:

[image]

Is there a better way of displaying the discount form?

Comment: Can I ask why that has to be the case and not just sticking to one input?

Comment: For my use case, there are no standard discount values or sub totals.

Comment: Maybe you should establish one?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use a toggle switch ABSOLUTE | PERCENTAGE and have the user select which one he wants to use. For example: (don't mind the $ sign I did it quickly)

[image]

and let the user select between the two options.

This format works very well in use cases that I deal with. Buyers and bidders have to make numerous (100+) decisions in a day. It's easy to select and easy to scan a screen and to see quickly and easily what needs to be done and / or what has yet to be done.

Comment: +1 this is the simplest and clearest way I can think of to present the field.

Comment: And make sure that if I type `$` or `%` in the field the corresponding box is automatically selected, please. Don't make me use the mouse.

Comment: I would prefer [tohster's suggestion](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/78820/44275) instead. It doesn't require an extra control, takes no additional screen real estate, is natural, fast, works into the tab / keyboard flow with no effort (and without disrupting tab order by introducing unit selectors into the flow), lends itself to future support for other units without UI changes, and takes care of the issue WChargin mentioned in the above comment all in one go.

Comment: @WChargin - you're absolutely correct. If the user types in % the associated field ought to be activated.

Comment: @JasonC - I think there is more than one correct answer. Ultimately it depends upon what the users are thinking about when they're using the system and what their expectations are.

Comment: @Mayo 1) There are many correct answers, including this one, and 2) I prefer tohster's. Both of these things are true. :)

Comment: Yeah, this. Especially if you animate the symbols so they slide from one side to the other ($ on left of number, % on right). If you can update the total value live with changes to this field, I think that would make things even clearer.

Comment: @Rikki - If I was to decide this my first inclination would be to put the $ and the % on the left side of the number as well. I wanted to emphasize the toggle idea and not bring in other aspects into consideration.

Comment: I think you should redraw the image, because only after reading the text I could realize you meant the "$ %" is a toggle switch and not two separate push buttons. The image has a usability failure, which worsens user experience.

Answer (score 29):

@Mayo has, I think, the answer with the clearest affordance.

But, **if the discount field is going to be used frequently**, an approach that has been proven to work with many professional and productivity application is the **polymorphic input box**.

[image]

Applications like *Microsoft Word, PowerPoint, Photoshop, AutoCAD, Illustrator*, and others use these boxes effectively to allow users to **enter units quickly in a single input action** without involving additional mouse clicks or tabs.

---

Polymorphic inputs are a little more difficult for users to learn, but once they understand how to use them they are often **the fastest interface** to use. For forms with multiple fields, they also allow users to complete by tabbing through and filling fields without needing to pause to grab a mouse.

Here's a sketch for a discount field:

[image]

- In this case I've used a placeholder to instruct users around what to do.  You may want to add a <kbd>***?***</kbd> info icon or a tooltip if you think your users need more explanation.
- Note that it's important to include default behavior if the user types in a number without a unit (in this case, I've defaulted that to a $ amount).

---

***One more thing...***

For discount fields, number signing can often be confusing.  It's good practice to add some error reporting to show users what the correct signing is:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. For the number signing issue, why not just remove the minus sign from the field rather than report an error?  There is no ambiguity about what the user meant.

Comment: @dan1111 that would work but many UX designers prefer not to enforce that kind of validation silently because users can feel frustrated with typing a `-` and having it not show up. In this case I think the design logic isn't strong enough to make it an antipattern so it's just a matter of preference.

Comment: Hmmm.  How about a dialog box popping up that says "Are you sure you don't not want to make your discount unpositive?"

Comment: +1 for "_Polymorphic inputs are a little more difficult for users to learn, but once they understand how to use them they are often the fastest interface to use_" When the (majority of) target users are going to be using a form dozens or hundreds of times a day, it can be better sacrificing a little "_obvious to use_" in favour of "_quick to use_".

Answer (score 7):

I recommend Gustav's option #2. You can give both, allow both to be editable, and have the counterpart update to reflect the change, either as they type, or upon the input field losing focus.

This would also take care of the need to round. I could type 20% for the discount, and then tab to the absolute input field and round to the nearest dollar. In cases like this, sometimes a chain link icon is used to indicate that the two input fields are linked:

[image: Absolute-Relative Input Wireframe]

Comment: A non-functional chain icon may be confusing, because it can often be used to link or unlink the two values (such as length and width when resizing an image).

Comment: I like this approach. However, in your image above, I'd put the absolute value on the left and the percentage on the right so that it ends up written out like we write it normally - $32.43 and 0.64% instead of %0.64 and 32.43$.

Comment: That's a great point. I had it that way initially, for the reason you state, but I suspect that % is the more commonly-used option. If this is true, it makes sense to have it first, so that users are presented with the option they prefer first, and so they can tab to it more easily with the keyboard.

Answer (score 5):

The answers so far all focus on ease of understanding.  This is important, but if the tool will be frequently used, ease of use is also something to consider.

If the typical user is likely to use this feature many times, I would let the option be set by typing % or a currency symbol directly in the field along with the value.  This will allow an expert to set the discount in only one action, rather than two.

This need not replace another, easier to understand way of setting the value.  You could also have a drop-down (or one of the other suggested paradigms) that you keep in sync with what is shown in the field.

Answer (score 3):

I see 3 options:

### 1: The switch.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyuhgQ.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Use common symbols like $ | %

---

### 2: Show both.

32.43 (0.64%)

---

### 3: Take over responsibility.

And decide what's the best for your users. Ask what they want to see, why they want to see it.

- **Marketing** purposes: go for the one which suits better the discount-value ratio. E.g. Use percentage on lower values, except if the the discount is very high. More: [Power of comparison](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2011/01/the-power-of-comparison-how-it-affects-decision-making.php), [Price experiments](http://conversionxl.com/pricing-experiments-you-might-not-know-but-can-learn-from/)
- **Billing**: Use absolute values
- **Something else**: Know your user group, what do they expect? What matches the business goals?

I can't imagine any situation where a user action would make the UI more usable and comfortable.

Comment: They require both. I would prefer percentages. However, as in the example above, they sometimes use the discounts to round up a figure.

Comment: Would it make sense to offer an option "round up" so they don't have to enter the value manually?

Comment: If I did I would have to give them the ability to select a round down level i.e ones, tens, hundreds etc. Seems like overkill.

Comment: Your answer is just as good as Mayo's but unfortunately I can only mark one as the answer. +1.

Answer (score 1):

If somebody writes 40% it's clear that it is a perecentage, and not an absolute value. Why not use that?

If the last character in the input field is an '%' you can store the value as percentage, otherwise as an absolute value. Next to the input field you could show an hint like 'enter absolute or perecentage value'.

Comment: There is the chance of someone forgetting to input the '%'. A visual indication as in the other answers is useful in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is good, but I prefer the $ symbol go on the left. Thus, I created a widget that preserves the normal positions of these symbols:

[image: Figma design for $/% input]